# Bucket Sort algorithm issues c#

Tags: c#

I am learning about sorting algorithms, and am currently at a loss with my first "Distribution Pass". As my notations describe, the first loop is where I sort each value into my bucket array based on the one's value. It works for every value except for the 9th index of my values array. The loop terminates before it gets to the 9th index. I've tried changing the conditions of the for loop, but that doesn't seem to work. Some help or hints as to what is happening would be much appreciated!

** Edit this is not the complete algorithm, it is only the first two steps. I am following the instructions from my c# book. The notes placed before each loop are the word for word instructions from the book. I don't want to continue with the sorting algorithm until I get the first loop working properly.

```
    public static void Sort(int[] values)
    {
        int n = values.Length;
        int[,] buckets = new int[n, n - 1];
        int index = 0;

        // Place each value of the one-dimensional array
        // into a row of the bucket array, based on the
        // value's "one's" (rightmost) digit.
        // "Distribution Pass"
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length -1; ++i)
        {
            // Get the one's value of values[i]
            int ones = (values[i] % 10);

            // Place the value in the appropriate bucket
            buckets[ones, i] = values[i];
        }


        // Loop through the bucket array row by row, 
        // and copy  the values back to the original
        // array.
        // "Gathering Pass"                           
        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < n - 1; c++)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (buckets[r, c] != 0)
                    {
                        values[index] = buckets[r, c];
                        index++;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] randomArray = new int[10];

        label1.Text = "Unsorted Array: ";
        label2.Text = "   Sorted Array: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.Length; i++)
        {
            randomArray[i] = rand.Next(10, 100);
            label1.Text += randomArray[i] + " ";
        }

        Sort(randomArray);
        label2.Text += string.Join(" ", randomArray);
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to assume your issue is because you keep doing subtraction for your lengths, more than likely have ten values and instead subtract to a nine and that tenth iteration would be out of bounds.

Comment: The variable ones will be equal to a value between 0 and 9 and there could be at most n of these numbers so the dimensions of your buckets array is incorrect. Try this instead:

    int[,] buckets = new int[10, n];
However, since you don't ever compare any values within the list of unsorted values so I don't see how this will ever sort them.

My understanding of bucket sort was that you group values as a prerequisite to a sorting algorithm. Are you possibly confusing it with radix sort? Radix sort sorts values by each digit from the least significant to most significant digits.